# How to discover my own IP address after login?

Tags: linux, ssh, scripting

When I use SSH to connect to a Linux server, I see a message informing me about the origin of my last login. For instance:

```
Last login: Mon Jul  7 14:37:09 2014 from host.example.net
```

I would like to know if it's possible to discover the IP/hostname from my current session (that is, the machine that I'm logging from right now).

Comment: yes sorry it's a dupe - i did search but didn't see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting `man 1 ssh`:

> ENVIRONMENT
>
> ```
> ssh will normally set the following environment variables:
>
> SSH_CONNECTION
> ```
>
> Identifies the client and server ends of the connection.  The variable contains four space-separated values: client IP address, client port number, server IP address, and server port number.

Other SSH servers than OpenSSH (e.g. Dropbear) might behave differently, check their documentation.

Use `dig -x x.x.x.x +short` to get the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `who` command and `w` command, those can give you the ip address of current logged in users.  It's not clear if you want the ip of the user running the script or of a given username.  You could parse the result from `who` if you already know the username in question.